# How can I stop my animation looping (Dope Sheet)

Tags: animation, rigging

Hello i'm new to Blender and animations,and I have no idea how can I stop my animation from looping infinitely...
Could someone tell me please how to stop it?

Comment: Depends on what animation, how you animated it and how you are playing it. Please edit your question and provide relevant information, as it stands this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I'm really sorry i'm like really new to this stuff... I used Dope sheet, does that help?

Comment: Also I see there's Blend-Exchange here, can I send you the project? it's just FPS hands that I animated to like fire a gun

Comment: If you are talking about playing back your scene's animation using "play" in the timeline window, or "Alt+A", then the 2015's answer that I linked above suggests that there is no option to avoid it looping, but you can try through a script.

Comment: Yes i'm talking about the timeline when I press play it just loops, i'm not sure how to do it with script..So maybe could I send you the project?

Comment: Look to the right In timeline mode. It should be start: 0, end: 260.  My "end" was set to 2 and that's why it was looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script with the following code. Run it once after you start blender and now the playback will stop at the value you have in the end box (ending range).

```
import bpy

def stop_playback(scene):
    if(scene.frame_current == scene.frame_end):
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(stop_playback)
```

Comment: You need at "tab" before bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False) this editor seems to have removed it